# Cannot change created custom Status Reason via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, xrmservicetoolkit

I have changed `salesorder` entity and create a new `status reason` in `Submitted`.
I have added a `status reason` named `PreTransport` in `submitted` state, with value `100000004`.
I can go from `Active` `state`(`pending status reason`) to `Submitted` `state`(`In-Progress` `status reason`) via this request :

```
          var request = ""
           request += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
           request += "  <s:Body>";
           request += "    <Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
           request += "      <request i:type=\"b:SetStateRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
           request += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
           request += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "            <c:key>EntityMoniker</c:key>";
           request += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
           request += "              <a:Id>" +recordGuid+ "</a:Id>";
           request += "              <a:LogicalName>salesorder</a:LogicalName>";
           request += "              <a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
           request += "            </c:value>";
           request += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "            <c:key>State</c:key>";
           request += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
           request += "              <a:Value>"+stateCode+"</a:Value>";
           request += "            </c:value>";
           request += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "            <c:key>Status</c:key>";
           request += "            <c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
           request += "              <a:Value>"+statusCode+"</a:Value>";
           request += "            </c:value>";
           request += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
           request += "        </a:Parameters>";
           request += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
           request += "        <a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>";
           request += "      </request>";
           request += "    </Execute>";
           request += "  </s:Body>";
           request += "</s:Envelope>";
           //send set state request  
           var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
           req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web", true)
           // Responses will return XML. It isn't possible to return JSON.
           req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
           req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
           req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
           var successCallback = null;
           var errorCallback = null;
           req.send(request );
```

But it does not work from `In-Progress` to `PreTransport` that are in the same `state`.
I suppose that it because of `permission`. Should I set Permission on this new `status reason`?

If yes How can I do this? 
Note that I have CRM 2011 on-premise.

Note: I have tried this code also, but no success.

```
XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.SetState("salesorder", Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(), 1, 100000004,false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have access to 2011 version. But I tested this below snippet in [CRM Rest builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder), It works perfectly.

I have created a custom `status reason (StatusCode)` of value `100000000 : Shipping ready` under `status (StateCode)` of `1 : Submitted`. Make sure you are flowing through the allowed transitions like [answered here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/214814).

```
var entity = {};
entity.StateCode = {
    Value: 1
};
entity.StatusCode = {
    Value: 100000000
};

XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Update("B4B625A1-3789-E811-A967-000D3A1A9407", entity, "SalesOrderSet", function() {
    //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
}, function(error) {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
}, true);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried within `Submitted` state, on a record from `In-Progress` to `Shipping ready`.